# SQL Request syntax error with INTO OUTFILE instruction

Tags: csv, mariadb, export

Can you help me with this request ?

```
TABLE ben INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/import/output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

I have this error :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE ben INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/import/output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED ';' LIN' at line 1

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to [SELECT .... INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing a 'by`

```
TABLE ben INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/import/output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Resource on usage: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: 1064 is _very_ good at pointing to where the error is; it is pointing at `TABLE`, not the spot that is missing `by`.

Comment: @Rick Hmmm. Aside from the syntax, didn't see anything wrong with his code itself. It's a one liner and the error message starts where the line starts and ends near the missing 'by'. Wish he let us know what was wrong.

Comment: No statement _begins_ with `TABLE`.  AD7six's Comment points out the likely syntax.

Comment: @Rick Which is what I thought too until I saw "INTO OUTFILE can also be used with a TABLE statement when you want to dump all columns of a table into a text file" in the documentation.

Comment: The "TABLE statement" was only recently added to MySQL 8.0.19; I see no mention of it in MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

The "TABLE statement" was not added until MySQL 8.0.19.  Since you are not running that version, you need to use the slightly more verbose version  `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ... FROM ben ...;`  (See Gandalf's answer for a link and another syntax error.)